# Streaming Twitter Error : Error parsing twitter reply: `Exceeded connection limit for user`

Tags: twitter, stream

I'm trying to stream twitter status in Node.js, but keep getting that error. What is Twitter limitation for such connection ? Or what that error means ?

Btw, it's still in development, so I might try to restart app frequently. I thought that was the problem. Is it true ?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter generally don't allow you to establish too many connections to the streaming API at the same time with the same set of credentials.
In my case, work finally done by unifying all the wanted changing "Track" as one string, and seperating by "," which means OR between each. Then you filter the results as your wish.

Comment: How to make a website with such limits. I mean 10 users will be visiting the site at once